# Unity: Drag on Screen and instantiate game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I continuously  instantiate Game objects by dragging on screen with unity and making the game object to follow the direction of the dragging?

For example: Drag right instantiates right, Drag up instantiates up or drag upwards at a certain angle and instantiates accordingly.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried already? I can help you more from there

Comment: Sorry I am new to unity and I haven't tried anything yet cause I don't even know where to start can you just point me in the right direction. I do know how to attach scripts to game objects though.

Comment: I'm sorry but SO isn't a code-on-demand service. If you want pointers I'd say to start with the basic tutorials from the unity and get a grasp of the basics.

Comment: Alright hold on I would try something out and see how it goes then I will edit my post thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have done so far or how good you are in programming, but the basic principle would be

1. Create a *DragInstantiate* Script, which you put on a GameObject on your Scene, but not the one you want to Instantiate.
2. In the Update Method of this Script you have to check, if the left mouse button is pressed down. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html
3. When you registered the click you have to save the position of the click. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html
4. The next step is to check when the left mouse button is released and again save the position. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonUp.html
5. From these two positions you can really easy calculate the direction, in which the object should move. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DirectionDistanceFromOneObjectToAnother.html
6. The last thing is to instantiate the object and set it's moving direction. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

Comment: Thanks that is really informative. I will go and give it a try right now 

Comment: Your welcome, if you have any more questions or problems feel free to ask. However I can also highly recommend the Unity tutorials or other youtube videos https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials